# Google Admobs Xcode warnings

Tags: swift, xcode, admob, warnings

I have installed Google Admobs via Cocoapods everything works as expected except that I have 38 warnings - this is with the latest version of Admobs - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.66.0) and with Xcode 12.01

Any ideas ?

Thanks

[image: Xcode errors for Admobs]

Answer (score 1):

You can disable all warnings from your cocoapods by adding this line to your `Podfile`:

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

Or you can disable warnings for a specific pod by appending this:

```
pod 'Eureka', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

If you want to get rid of the warnings - and not just hide them - you can try deintegrating and reinstalling the cocoapods like this:

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

If the warnings don't disappear, the cocoapod likely needs to be updated to work properly with Xcode 12.